# Rails HTML Table update fields in mongo with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, mongodb, mongoid

I'm building a Rails app backed by mongodb using mongoid.

It's a one page app, with a HTML table, every field for every row of which, needs to be editable without refreshing the page.

This is your usual Rails view ( like many in rails casts ) showing a table with rows and columns containing data.

For example. I'm showing cars, and showing their make, model and notes

They way I'm doing this is by appending _id of a mongo document to every column and marking it's field name in html id too. Then I pick up the value for $("#id") and send it to rails controller via AJAX and run @car.update_attributes method accordingly.

Currently, one of my rows looks like this.

```
    <tr>
       <td id=<%= car.id %>_make>
       <%= car.make %>
       </td>

       <td id=<%= car.id %>_model>
       <%= car.model %> 
       </td>

       <td id=<%= car.id %>_notes>
       <%= car.notes %>
       </td>
     </tr>

     // my function which is called onChange for every column
     function update_attributes(id){
        var id = id.split[0];
        var attribute = id.split[1];
        $.ajax("sending id and attribute to rails controller");
     }
```

Is there any built it Rails magic which would let me update only a field in a model without refreshing the page?

or.

Is there a Rails plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

For what you're describing (a one-page ajax centric app), I strongly recommend using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). You could alternatively accomplish this by other simpler gems (or even manually writing jquery ajax), but I find you quickly become disorganized in an ajax-centric app.  One of the biggest upsides of backbone.js is how well it keeps your ajax code organized. Try using the [backbone-rails gem](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) which can have you up and running in a few minutes with the help of excellent built-in scaffolding.

To more directly answer your question, ajax is not "built-in" to rails in the sense you're looking for it,  but there are gems that can help you do this more easily (such as the backbone-rails).

Answer (score 0):

Also there is gem called [rest_in_place](https://github.com/janv/rest_in_place) which is specially made for this purpose. You will need to do very little configuration to perform in place editing. Your controller just needs to have all the restfull methods.